# I lost my prevous account on StackOverflow due to the forced "Social Login"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, login

I used to have another account here but not I am being forced to log in with social channels.  The email I used and password are not accessible.  Has anyone else ran into this and do you have a fix?  It is rather annoying being cast as a noobie.  Did StackOverflow move the "login by email and password" feature or is clicking on the buttons representing your social channel the only way in?

Answer (score 7):

OpenID is not social login.

Anyway to enter your email and password just choose "log in with Stack Exchange", the left most option:

[image: screenshot]

And you will be able to sign in with your email and password.

Comment: A hand-drawn _blue_ circle? Seriously?

Comment: @cdeszaq didn't know hand drawn circle has to be in specific color.. ? I usually use blue for informative circles and red for circles around bad stuff. :)

Comment: I _suppose_ that makes sense. Red just _draws_ attention better. But, what abut green? Does green get a special place in your of informative annotation palette?

Comment: @cdeszaq green might fit for wrapping stuff representing success, will pose serious competition to blue in such case. ;)

Comment: @MrLister hmm.. any official support for your claim (green better than blue)? I'm far from being graphic designer so any tips are welcome. :-)

Comment: I like to just pick a good contrast-y color. My default choice is red, unless there's a lot of red in the background. How has this not already been discussed *ad nauseum* on Meta?

Comment: @Cody guess I'm the first to break the tradition.. no? :-)